# NavEE manual links target not working

Tags: navee

Am using EE 2.10.2 and NavEE 2.2.10

Whenever am assigning target blank or parent or any target to manual links it is not working. Probably a bug, not sure.

Did anyone encounter this?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, should have included the variable {target} in the attribute, target="{target}"